How can I avoid returning a non-optional group that is undefined?
I've two possible strings:

TEXT1, TEXT2\n\nTEXT3
TEXT1, TEXT2

Each text should be extracted without the comma and new line characters. I'm able to extract the first one with:
const regex = /^\s*(.*),\s*(.*)(?:[\n]{0,2}(.*?))?$/g
regex.exec(desc) \\ Returns ['TEXT1, TEXT2\n\nTEXT3', 'TEXT1', 'TEXT2', 'TEXT3']

But the second string returns undefined as last group result. How can I avoid returning it (just return ['TEXT1, TEXT2', 'TEXT1', 'TEXT2']?

If you don't need it returned, make it a non-capture group with (?:...)

Where exactly? I have that: (?:[\n]{0,2}(.*?))?

(?:.*?) will make that a non-capture group as well.

I tried this and it's still undefined: /^\s*(.*),\s*(.*)(?:[\n]{0,2}(?:(.*)))?$/g

That's not what I wrote. (?:(.*)) should be just (?:.*)

@Barmar it doesn't return TEXT3 with your example

I thought you didn't want that. There's no way to have it return something when it matches, and not when it doesn't. All capture groups are always returned.

Consider if the one you didn't want was in the middle, not at the end. How would you know which one was skipped?

Okay, then it's like this and I need to check for an undefined group

What if you have input that starts with a comma, like ", a" then what will the expected result be? What if the input ends with one or more spaces? Do you really want to capture those?

Consider using split using / *, *|\n+/

If you write: /^\s*(.*),\s*(.*)\n?\n?(.*)$/g you obtain an empty group instead of an undefined group. Note that [^,\n]* for the first capture group will be more efficient than .*
